# Running several instances of a console application with php

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I'm running an apache server on a windows 7 machine.

I made two script:

1. Holds an html file that calls the second multiple times via `ajax` and outputs the result.
2. When called loads a **console application** which performs a simple task and write the result back.

The application is executed with php `exec()` (tested with `proc_open()` too) and everything seems to work fine even with several ("simultaneously" ajax calls)

`mpm` is enabled - `mpm-winnt` is used.

I noticed that if I fire several ajax calls - lets assume 20 calls - the apache server only **opens simultaneously 6 processes at max** (of the exe file). 
Even when I watch the processes tab in the task manager I can only see 6 instances of the application being executed in parallel. I expect ~20 - it seems the other calls are waiting for the pool of 6...

Any Idea why? and how can I force the server to increase this "pool"?

**EDIT - more information**

Apache 2.4 (x64)

PHP 5.6 (x64) - used as an apache module.

[httpd.conf](http://textuploader.com/54hnb)

[httpd-mpm.conf](http://textuploader.com/54hw3)

If i open the program manually it loads as many times as I want.

If I don't use ajax and I open 20 tabs that loads the application - same 6 pool.

The program uses ~70mb (peak) of memory for each instance.

Comment: Can you post your Apache config?

Comment: check `apache's` `maxclient` and `MaxRequestsPerChild` directives

Comment: @anonymous `MaxClient` is an mpm-common setting that is not used by the `mpm-winnt` the only relates setting of `mpm-winnt` are `MaxRequestsPerChild` and `ThreadsPerChild` which did not affect my problem.

Comment: this maybe? http://serverfault.com/questions/105908/how-do-you-increase-the-apache-connection-limit-wamp

Comment: @chiliNut as I mentioned I'm using mpm-winnt already this question is answered by enabling mpm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limitation isn't server side, but maintained by the web browsers.
**RFC** suggest that this limitation must be set 2 per servers, but web browsers aren't conform :) 
I've found this information from [BrowserScope - Max Connections Per Hostname](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top-d)

```
Browser | Version | Connections per Hostname | Max Connections
--------+---------+--------------------------+----------------
Chrome  | 32→     | 6                        | 10
Firefox | 26→     | 6                        | 17
IE      | 9→      | 6                        | 35
IE      | 10→     | 8                        | 17
IE      | 11→     | 13                       | 17   
Safari  | 7.0.1→  | 6                        | 17
```

Comment: thank you! I was aware of the Max connection but didn't know about the per Hostname part... always thought ajax is outside this scope - switching to firefox :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how do you connect to server (via AJAX or by opening multiple tabs). It's anyway affected by limitations that Halayem mentioned above.

For example, if you would try to call php script via another net tool like cURL I'm sure you will see as many program instances as requests were were sent.